# How to config nginx as sticky loadbalancer for both http and https

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, sticky-sessions

I have the config below. However, when user switch from http to https, the session doesn't stick no more. Eg. homepage http but payment page is https.

How do I solve this?

```
upstream backend  {
    ip_hash;
    server <server-1-ip>;
    server <server-2-ip>;
}

upstream backend_ssl {
    ip_hash;
    server <server-1-ip>:443;
    server <server-2-ip>:443;
}

server {
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/mycert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/mykey.key;
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://backend_ssl;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm quite unsure about the problem you're trying to solve. "[...] the session doesn't stick no more. Eg. homepage http but payment page is https [...]": Please elaborate.

Comment: Eg user go to homepage (server1) but  going to payment page, they were redirected to (server2)

Comment: Because the protocol switches from http to https i guess. Sorry cant edit old comment on mobile

Answer (score 1):

Well, I guess, because you're using two `upstream` groups, the state isn't shared between the two groups. Right now I can't test this further, but here are some ideas of mine:

- Use one `upstream` group, inspect the `$scheme`, leverage [map](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) with a variable to assign the correct ports to the `$scheme` (either http or https), and use this variable in your `server` directive, so this becomes `server <server-1-ip>:$variable`.
- Use [zone](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#zone) which "keeps the group’s configuration and run-time state that are shared between worker processes. Several groups may share the same zone."
- Instead of using `ip_hash`, you could insert a cookie containing the correct backend server (which will be used for all further requests) using [sticky](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#sticky).

Note: This is not a copy-paste one-size-fits-all answer, but merely some quick ideas of mine. Read the docs, and you'll find a solution. Good luck and all the best!

Comment: `zone` directive is unknown. it seems it's not available in open-source version. `sticky` seems to require domains which i'm not aware. it's managed by the upstream. I will try `map`.

Comment: @TuanAnhTran `zone` is in the open source version, but, according to the docs, "This directive appeared in version 1.9.0."; not sure which version you're running right now. "sticky seems to require domains which i'm not aware. it's managed by the upstream.": Don't understand this, please elaborate.